# Some attributes/fields of "Sheet" object is not documented but is present in Get Sheet API response?

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I noticed that some of the fields/attributes related to "Get Sheet" API has attributes like:
[Not documented attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2EsX.png)
which are not documented in the API doc
https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Sheet-Object

[Postman API response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOzYO.png)

Could anyone please help in knowing what exactly is the reason to this? Are these to be considered? What description do I consider for each of them?

Comment: This question should be directed to Smartsheet support instead of being posted here on Stack Overflow. You've discovered an issue with their API docs -- only they will be able to fix it and in the meantime, provide you with more info about these (currently undocumented) properties. To report this issue to Smartsheet, use [this form](https://help.smartsheet.com/contact/smartsheetapp) -- for **How can we halp?** select **I want to report an issue** -- for **Select a Topic** select **API and Technical Questions** -- for **API and Technical Questions Feature** select **Other**.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I thought I was missing something out here. However, I have reported the issue as you suggested, thanks much. Hoping it gets resolved by the support team.

Comment: Happy to help, and thanks for reporting to Smartsheet!